# How to wait nested task?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose  I have the following situation:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Task.Run(() => DoWork())
      .ContinueWith((prev) => 
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
      }
}

public void DoWork()
{
    Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation());
    Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation2());
    Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation3());
}
```

I need to wait all the tasks within `DoWork` have finished before showing `Hello World`, actually my code will display `Hello World` but the task inside the method are still running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could return a `Task` that waits for all Tasks, using [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public Task DoWork()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation()),
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation2()),
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation3()));
}
```

Note: to follow conventions, you should call this `DoWorkAsync`:

```
public Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation()),
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation2()),
        Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation3()));
}
```

Also, the operations are already running on different threads, you don't need `Task.Run` to call `DoWorkAsync`:

```
DoWorkAsync()
    .ContinueWith((prev) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    };
```

Comment: .. and call it `DoWorkAsync`

Comment: @DavidG Sure it is.  It returns a `Task` immediately that represents work completing later.  That makes it asynchronous.  The `async` keyword is just a tool for making asynchronous methods easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) call inside `DoWork`.

*example pesudocode*

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation2()));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation3()));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I doesn't have WaitForAll, why?

Comment: @utop Typo, he meant to say `WaitAll()`

Comment: @utop: yes, that's right. It was a typo sorry. corrected.